# What are html templating alternatives for Django?

Tags: python, html, model-view-controller, templates

Please note I'm coming from a Ruby & Node.js world and would like to use something concise and not neccessarily complex.

Would be great to use haml but it's not required.

I was looking at Jinja2 but it seems to be a better implementation of roughly the same idea as standard templates which seem IMHO overengineered a bit. If you think this is not the case, I'd like to hear such opinion too.

TIA

Comment: What is your motivation to not use Django?

Comment: Django's templates are really, really nice.  They can be "concise".  They can't be complex because a great many things are simply forbidden from the templates.  Real code has to be in the view functions, not the templates.  I think Django's templates are total victory.  Why do you object to them?

Comment: Have you read [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/templates/)? Anything that makes a simple job that complicated is broken on some level.

Comment: Hmmm, that question was asked 7 years ago.. and has been answered already at that time

Comment: You may take a look on yawrap: https://pypi.org/project/yawrap/ Templateless pure pythonic and ridiculusly fast html generator. It's a nice alternative.

Comment: I will repeat: this answer was needed 7 years ago.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Templating in Python](http://wiki.python.org/moin/Templating) lists a bunch.

Comment: Bah I forgot this is the primary wiki of all things pythonic. Thx!

Comment: @Wojciech: you're welcome. It took me all of 5 seconds to Google up an answer ;-)

Answer (score 2):

I think the closest thing you are going to find is something like [Brevé](http://breve.twisty-industries.com/)

**HAML:**

```
#profile
  .left.column
    #date= print_date
    #address= current_user.address
  .right.column
    #email= current_user.email
    #bio= current_user.bio
```

**Brevé**

```
div ( id = 'profile' ) [
    div ( _class = 'left column' ) [
        div (id = "date") [ 
            today() # Assumes we have a function called `today` registered.
        ]
        div (id = "address") [ 
            current_user.address
        ]
    ]
    div ( _class = 'right column' ) [
        div (id = "email") [ 
            current_user.email
        ]
        div (id = "bio") [ 
            current_user.bio
        ]
    ]
]
```

Breve also has a tool that [converts HTML to Breve code](http://breve.twisty-industries.com/tools).